# RSS pubsubhubbub implementation

Tags: ruby, rss, websub

According to [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/RssFeeds) I need add

```
      <link rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"/>
```

to my channel tag, but my channel already contains a link tag to my own site, and adding another link means I can't pass verification because of there being two link tags in the same channel.

Unfortunately I couldn't open new issue in pubsubhubbub

Is there any way to deal with two link in the same channel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can add several the `<link>` tags in your `<channel>`, but the link tags need to be in the Atom namespace, not in the RSS namespace, and yes, they can both be used in the same feed, as long as you prefix tags in the atom namespace with `atom` and later define what it means by using `xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`.

For example, you can have this :

```
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="hub" href="http://superfeedr.com"/>
```

Also remember that the namespace definitions are "herited" from the parent elements. SO you can just add in the `<channel>` element and you can just write:

```
<atom:link rel="hub" href="http://superfeedr.com"/>
```

**UPDATE** The answer above applies to PubSubHubbub 0.3 which was specific to both RSS/Atom feeds. The [latest version](http://pubsubhubbub.github.io/PubSubHubbub/pubsubhubbub-core-0.4.html) of the spec brings support for *any* mime type, which means that discovery has to be performed at the HTTP level using 2 `Link` headers.

Comment: OK, but how can I define rss and atom in the same file? It seems like I can use either rss or feed. The second question is if I am going to use Atom I need to change all structure of file with tags. For instance, I want to add <link rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"/> and link to <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="title" href="http://site/rss.xml" />

Comment: @com. Namespaces are one of the strengths of XML `<atom:link>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not defining your feed as an atom feed you can do this:

```
<link>http://www.your-site.com/</link>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"/>
```

the xmls:atom attribute has to be there to use the atom namespace.  I don't think you would need to use more than once though.  With the atom namespace you can use more than one link.